# Почему Delphi не предупреждает, когда происходит выход за пределы статического массива?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

1. Очень долго искал почему же у меня динамический массив в 1 момент вдруг заполняется мусором и всегда на 9 элементов и теряется доступ к нему (access violation при setlength 0). В итоге каждую строчку отдебажил и нашел именно ту после которой происходит проблема.[image: Скрин проблемы]
   Как оказалось playersstate у меня от 1 до 255, а id = 0. Т.е. выход за пределы массива. Почему делфи не выдал ошибку что я вышел за пределы массива?
2. Почему когда происходит ошибка в функции, то при нажатии на stop меня кидает на строчку после вызова функции?
3. Почему у меня синтаксис часто подсвечивается некорректно [image: Синтаксис]
   Почему тут голубое стало? Поставил `{` и сразу же убрал перед голубым цветом и стало норм.
4. Почему он мне пишет часто, что в строчке ошибка, хотя там нет ошибки и компилятор пишет что нет ошибки и работает корректно. А потом вдруг раз и ошибки в строчке нет для IDE. При этом это delphi 10.3.

Comment: Не нравится `Delphi` - осваивайте другие технологии. А, вопрос лучше или отредактировать в соответствии с правилами сообщества или удалить вовсе, потому, что сейчас это просто поток эмоций (простите за прямоту).

Comment: А всего-то надо включить проверку на выход за диапазон массива в настройках компилятора ..

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку проверка валидности индекса замедляет работу программы, по-умолчанию она отключена. Но вы можете использовать ключ компилятора для её включения (в пределах юнита): `{$RANGECHECKS ON}` или `{R+}` и тогда, при выходе индекса за границы массива, будет генерироваться исключение `ERangeError`.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Range_checking

Так же, эту проверку можно включить для всего проекта в целом, через настройки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо, а остальные проблемы решаются?

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas По каждой *отдельной* проблеме задавайте *отдельный* вопрос. Мы же не на форуме.

Comment: воу, в какой версии темный интерфейс появился?

Comment: @teran [New in 10.2.2: Dark IDE Theme!](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/new-in-10-2-2-dark-ide-theme)